# 'pdflatex' not found in subprocess within a bundled PyInstaller APP

Tags: python, subprocess, latex, pyinstaller, pdflatex

I am attempting to create a macOS standalone app from a `PyQt5` GUI using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/). All works apart from automatically generating a PDF from a TEX file using the [pdflatex](https://pypi.org/project/pdflatex/) module (in conjunction with [Pylatex](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/)).

Both the `pylatex` and `pdflatex` modules require calling the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module, which is done as following:

```
fp = subprocess.run(args, input=self.latex, env=env, timeout=15, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Where `args=['pdflatex', '-output-directory=/Users/Desktop', '-interaction-mode=batchmode', '-jobname=test']`

This however does not work within the bundled app as it is crashing with the following error which I am logging to a file:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdflatex'
```

Evidently, the `pdflatex` executable isn't being included/ found in the bundle. Running `which pdflatex` in the terminal outputs the following directory: `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` So I have tried to add the path with the following PyInstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile --path "/Library/TeX/texbin" main.py
```

But the app still cannot find the `pdflatex` executable at runtime, whereas the terminal executable works without issues. I have exhausted all similar posts online and ran out of things to try so I was hoping someone might guide me to the solution.

Related info:

- macOS version: 10.13.6 High Sierra
- Python: 3.8
- PyInstaller: 5.1

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I just solved it by editing the runtime environment generated by PyInstaller. In my case the `npm` command was not found and after running `which npm` in terminal I could see that npm was located in `/usr/local/bin`, path that is not included by PyInstaller on macOS.

So my solution is to run this at app startup:

```
local_bin = '/usr/local/bin'
if local_bin not in os.environ["PATH"]:
   os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + local_bin
```